# Why can't I make Google Chrome my default PDF viewer any more?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, pdf

I am trying to make Google Chrome the default program for opening PDF files on a Windows 7 PC. I right click the PDF and choose 'Open With'. Chrome is not listed, so I browse to its location (C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe) and click Open. Nothing happens.

This used to work, so what's changed?

Comment: have you installed any pdf viewer ?

Comment: about:plugins shows that Chrome PDF Viewer is installed and enabled. And if I drag a PDF file from Explorer into Chrome it does open up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. Chrome had somehow got itself partially uninstalled: it wasn't auto-updating anymore, and when I tried to uninstall it from the Control Panel, I was told it had already gone (though it was listed). I've just reinstalled, and it now shows up in the Open With dialog's list of programs again.